# Extra Page when using thmbox

Tags: thmbox

When I use the package thmbox by adding `\usepackage[S]{thmbox}` in my `.sty` file, an extra annoying page **before** my titlepage appears, which contains the text **"Remarks and Extensions"**.

Removing this line/command, affects that the page disappears again.

What's wrong there?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load `thmstyle`, the `\theoremstyle` declarations are ignored; moreover `\newtheorem*` is invalid.

The documentation of `thmbox` is not very clear; however, you can emulate the styles of `amsthm` quite easily:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[S]{thmbox}

\thmboxoptions{S,bodystyle=\itshape\noindent}
\newtheorem[S]{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem[S]{thm}[lem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem[S]{cor}[lem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem[S,bodystyle=\upshape\noindent]{defi}{Definition}

\newtheorem[
  S,
  bodystyle=\upshape\noindent,
  headstyle=\itshape Remarks and Extensions
]{rem}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\section{Title}

\begin{lem}
Something
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
Something
\end{thm}

\begin{cor}
Something
\end{cor}

\begin{rem}
Remark
\end{rem}

\begin{defi}
A definition
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On creating the MWE, I discovered the following line:

```
\theoremstyle{remark} \newtheorem*{rem}{Remarks and Extensions}
```

That's it! On deleting this, the mysterious page disappeared. I think thmbox doesn't supports `remark`.

Comment: Still a minimal example would be good for better understanding the issue.

Comment: Okay, have a look here:
http://pastebin.com/VdPYPMKc

Comment: Apart from the fact that the `S` style is terrible, the problem is in `\newtheorem*`, not in `\theoremstyle{remark}`.

Comment: S style? You mean the structure of the file? Like mentioned at the beginning, I deleted the (helpful) comments, but these were in german...

oh, that's right. It's the star. Thanks!